# How do you get the correct percent change from pandas.Dataframe's pct_change when there are two zeroes in a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, percentage

I would like pct_change to output 0 percent change when a 0 follows a 0, because that is what is happening.

My input dataframe has this in a column

```
---
|0|
---
|0|
---
```

The problem with pct_change is that the result from the input ends up with this

```
-----
|nan|
-----
```

There are nans in the input data frame, so I can't just replace all nans.

I could perform the percent change myself to get the correct results, but, as I see it, that would involve looping through rows in the input df and a shifted version of it, and checking for 0s in both, which seems like a very unpythonic way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with `pct_change` you are always going to struggle if your data contains a 0 in it. Would you be able to simply mask 0s where they occur in your data? I recommend mask only because if you have a 0 in one column and then a number in the next you will most like get an inf which I feel is not what you would want either

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : [100, 110, 0, 0, 100, 90]
})

df.mask(df['Column1'].eq(0)).pct_change()
```

Comment: 0 followed by any number but 0 seems like it should be inf, and for my use case, it fits because I need it to be greater than 0. Seems paradoxical, but for my use case, a change from 0 to 0 should be equal to 0.